# How can I add a few specific mesh (altitude-like level) curves to a plot?

Tags: plotting, graphics, version-7, mesh

I'm plotting the numerical solution of a differential equations, using the altitude-like level curves as a mesh.  It's fine, but I would like to add three specific altitude levels as thick red, green and blue curves, while all other curves stay in the default style.  Here's a simple MWE to play with:

```
Plot3D[
 Sin[x - y] + Cos[x + y], (* this function is just for the MWE *)
 {x, -10, 10},
 {y, -10, 10},
 PlotPoints -> {30, 30},
 PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}, {-3, 3}},
 MeshFunctions -> (#3 &),
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
 ImageSize -> 500,
 Method -> {"RotationControl" -> "Globe"},
 SphericalRegion -> True
 ]

ContourPlot[
 Sin[x - y] + Cos[x + y], (* this function is just for the MWE *)
 {x, -10, 10},
 {y, -10, 10},
 PlotPoints -> {30, 30},
 PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}},
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
 ImageSize -> 500
 ]
```

So I need this:

On both plots, I need to show the level curves for the alitude -1 (in thick red), 0 (in thick green) and +1 (in thick blue), while keeping all other curves as they currently are.  These curves should be independent of the particular function that I use in this MWE.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use multiple mesh functions in a plot, each with its own mesh definitions:

```
Plot3D[
 Sin[x - y] + Cos[x + y],
 {x, -10, 10},{y, -10, 10},
 PlotPoints -> {30, 30},
 PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}, {-3, 3}},
 Mesh -> {
   Range[-5, 5, 0.5] (*"regular" mesh*),
   {(*your own special lines*)
     {-1, Directive[Thick, Red]},
     {0, Directive[Thick, Green]},
     {1, Directive[Thick, Blue]}}
   },
 MeshFunctions -> {(#3 &),(#3&)},
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
 ImageSize -> 500,
 Method -> {"RotationControl" -> "Globe"},
 SphericalRegion -> True
]
```

[image: Plot3D with desired meshes]

---

It is even easier with `ContourPlot`, where you can just provide a list of contour values. Generate a list of standard contours with `Range`, styled by the `ContoursStyle` option, then `Join` it with a list of your special contours, hand-styled as you wish them to be.

```
ContourPlot[
 Sin[x - y] + Cos[x + y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10},
 PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}},
 PlotPoints -> {30, 30},
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",

 (* styling for default contours *)
 ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.3],
 Contours -> 
   Join[
     (* default contours *)
     Range[-5, 5, 0.33],
     (* your own hand-styled ones *)
     {
       {-1, Directive[Opacity[1, Red], Thick]},
       {0, Directive[Opacity[1, Green], Thick]},
       {1, Directive[Opacity[1, Blue], Thick]}
     }
   ],
 ImageSize -> 500
]
```

[image: contourplot with styled contours]

Comment: Is this also working for the CountourPlot?

Comment: Aaah!  Stupid I am!  I forgot your **MeshFunctions -> {(#3 &),(#3&)}**.  Now it's working!

Comment: How do you make the default mesh to have style?  I would add opacity 50% or gray level.

Comment: YES!  It works very nicely now!  Woowee, that was a lot of work!  Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I just noticed a mismatch in altitude curves on the 2D view.  The red, green and blue curves are perfect on the 3D view, but they aren't at their proper location on the 2D view.  I don't understand what is going on here, with the Join function: **Contours -> 
   Join[
     Range[-5, 5, 01/3],
     {
       {-1, Directive[Red, Thick]},
       {0, Directive[Green, Thick]},
       {1, Directive[Blue, Thick]}
     }
   ]**.  The curves are offset by 1 or 2 positions.

Comment: I found the cause of the wrong colorized curve placements: in your **Range** function, you get three duplicates of the curves that are defined after that part.  This cause a mismatch.

Answer (score 5):

**3D**

Set the `Mesh` to

```
 Mesh -> {{{-1, {Thick, Red}}, {0, {Thick, Green}}, {1, {Thick, 
        Blue}}}}
```

```
a = Plot3D[
   Sin[x - y] + 
    Cos[x + y],(*this function is just for the MWE*){x, -10, 
    10}, {y, -10, 10}, PlotPoints -> {30, 30}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}, {-3, 3}}, 
   MeshFunctions -> (#3 &), ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
   ImageSize -> 500, Method -> {"RotationControl" -> "Globe"}, 
   SphericalRegion -> True];
b = Plot3D[Sin[x - y] + Cos[x + y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
   PlotPoints -> {30, 30}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}, {-3, 3}}, 
   MeshFunctions -> (#3 &), 
   Mesh -> {{{-1, {Thick, Red}}, {0, {Thick, Green}}, {1, {Thick, 
        Blue}}}}, PlotStyle -> None];
Show[a, b]
```

[image]

**2D**

Set `Contours`

```
Contours -> {{-1, {Thick, Red}}, {0, {Thick, Green}}, {1, {Thick, 
       Blue}}}
```

```
aa = ContourPlot[
   Sin[x - y] + 
    Cos[x + y],(*this function is just for the MWE*){x, -10, 
    10}, {y, -10, 10}, PlotPoints -> {30, 30}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
   ImageSize -> 500];
bb = ContourPlot[Sin[x - y] + Cos[x + y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
   PlotPoints -> {30, 30}, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}, 
   ImageSize -> 500, ContourShading -> None, 
   Contours -> {{-1, {Thick, Red}}, {0, {Thick, Green}}, {1, {Thick, 
       Blue}}}];
Show[aa, bb]
```

Or this?

```
aa = ContourPlot[
   Sin[x - y] + 
    Cos[x + y],(*this function is just for the MWE*){x, -10, 
    10}, {y, -10, 10}, PlotPoints -> {30, 30}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
   ImageSize -> 500, MeshFunctions -> (#3 &), Mesh -> None, 
   ContourStyle -> None, ContourShading -> Automatic];
bb = ContourPlot[Sin[x - y] + Cos[x + y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
   PlotPoints -> {30, 30}, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}, 
   ImageSize -> 500, ContourShading -> None, ContourStyle -> None, 
   MeshFunctions -> (-#3 &), 
   Mesh -> {{{-1, {Thick, Red, Opacity[1]}}, {0, {Thick, Green, 
        Opacity[1]}}, {1, {Thick, Blue, Opacity[1]}}}}];
Show[aa, bb]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

All the methods below add three styled curves, ***"while all other curves stay in the default style."***

#### ContourPlot

**1.** You can use the options `MeshFunctions` and `Mesh` to add additional contours:

```
ContourPlot[Sin[x - y] + Cos[x + y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
 PlotPoints -> {30, 30}, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", ImageSize -> 500,
 MeshFunctions -> {Sin[# - #2] + Cos[# + #2] &}, 
 Mesh -> {Thread[{{0., -1., 1.}, 
     Thread[Directive[{Green, Red, Blue}, Thick, Opacity[1]]]}]}]
```

[image]

**2.** Generate the list of contours using [`FindDivisions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindDivisions.html) and style each contour as you like:

```
automaticcontours = FindDivisions[{-2, 2}, 10];

styledcontours = {{-1, Directive[Thick, Red]}, 
   {0, Directive[Thick, Green]}, {1, Directive[Thick, Blue]}};

contours = DeleteDuplicatesBy[First]@
   Join[styledcontours, Thread[{automaticcontours, Automatic}]];

ContourPlot[Sin[x - y] + Cos[x + y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
 PlotPoints -> {30, 30}, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", ImageSize -> 500, 
 Contours -> contours]
```

[image]

**3.** Post-process `ContourPlot` output to restyle selected contours:

```
cp = ContourPlot[Sin[x - y] + Cos[x + y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
  PlotPoints -> {30, 30}, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", ImageSize -> 500];

Replace[cp, {Tooltip[{d___, l__Line}, t : (0. | 1. | -1.)] :> {Thick, Opacity[1], 
    t /. {0. -> Green, -1. -> Red, 1. -> Blue, _ -> {d}},  Tooltip[{l}, t]}}, All]
```

[image]

**4.** Yet another method is to extract the contours from `cp` and redo `ContourPlot` using styled contours:

```
automaticcontours = Cases[cp, Tooltip[_, t_] :> t, All]
```

> ```
> {1.5, 1., 0.5, 0., -0.5, -1., -1.5};
> ```

```
styledcontours = Thread[{{0., -1., 1.}, 
     Thread[Directive[{Green, Red, Blue}, Thick, Opacity[1]]]}];

contours = Join[styledcontours , Complement[automaticcontours, {0., -1., 1.}]];

ContourPlot[Sin[x - y] + Cos[x + y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
 PlotPoints -> {30, 30}, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", ImageSize -> 500, 
 Contours -> contours]
```

[image]

#### Plot3D

**1.** Use [`FindDivisions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindDivisions.html) to generate a  mesh list (that matches the automatically generated one) and add your list of styled mesh lines and use the combined list as the setting for `Mesh`:

```
automaticmeshlines = Most @ Rest @ FindDivisions[{-2, 2}, 18];

styledmeshlines = {{-1, Directive[Thick, Red]}, {0, 
    Directive[Thick, Green]}, {1, Directive[Thick, Blue]}};

mesh = DeleteDuplicatesBy[First]@
  Join[styledmeshlines, Thread[{automaticmeshlines , Automatic}]];

Plot3D[Sin[x - y] + Cos[x + y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
 PlotPoints -> {30, 30}, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}, {-3, 3}},
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", ImageSize -> 500, 
 Method -> {"RotationControl" -> "Globe"}, SphericalRegion -> True,
 MeshFunctions -> {#3 &},
 Mesh -> {mesh}]
```

[image]

**2.** Add constant functions in the first argument of `Plot3D` corresponding to the desired levels, set their `PlotStyle` to `Opacity[0]` and use the option [`BoundaryStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoundaryStyle.html) to set the directives for the intersection of the main surface with the added planes:

```
Plot3D[{ 0., -1., 1., Sin[x - y] + Cos[x + y]}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10,
   10}, PlotPoints -> {30, 30}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}, {-3, 3}}, 
 MeshFunctions -> (#3 &), 
 PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0], Opacity[0], Opacity[0], Automatic}, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", ImageSize -> 500, 
 BoundaryStyle -> {1 -> None, 2 -> None, 3 -> None, 
   {4, 1} -> Directive[Green, AbsoluteThickness[4], Opacity[1]], 
   {4, 2} -> Directive[Red, AbsoluteThickness[4], Opacity[1]],
   {4, 3} -> Directive[Blue, AbsoluteThickness[4], Opacity[1]]}, 
 Method -> {"RotationControl" -> "Globe"}, SphericalRegion -> True]
```

[image]

**3.** Post-process to restyle selected mesh lines:

```
p3d = Plot3D[Sin[x - y] + Cos[x + y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
  PlotPoints -> {30, 30}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}, {-3, 3}}, 
  MeshFunctions -> (#3 &), ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  ImageSize -> 500, Method -> {"RotationControl" -> "Globe"}, 
  SphericalRegion -> True];

Normal[p3d] /. Line[x_, ___] :> 
  {Round[x[[1, -1]], 0.1] /. Append[Thread[{0., -1., 1.} -> 
    Thread[Directive[{Green, Red, Blue}, Thick, Opacity[1]]]], _ -> {}],  Line[x]}
```

[image]

Comment: The first method appears to be adapted to the specific function given as an example.  I need it to be independent of the function, since the real code is about displaying a numerical solution of some differential equation...

Comment: @Cham, in general, you can use the function in the first argument of `ContourPlot` as the mesh function. That is, use `ContourPlot[foo[x,y], ..., MeshFunctions->{foo[#,#2]&},....]` or `ContourPlot[foo[x,y], ..., MeshFunctions->{Function[{x,y},foo[x,y]]},....]`

Comment: Agreed.  But since my function is a numerical solution, I don't know how to set it up in there.  Using Phi[t,#1, #2]& alone doesn't work.  With Evaluate, it doesn't work neither, yet.